# Android edit DB record in list detail using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext

I woul like to edit my DB record using ListDetail. Currently my project display listView of exercises sorting by day. When u click on list position, you get new window with exercise's details. There are 2 buttons: edit and delete. Delete button is working good using intent, but I have no idea how to easily make EDIT button working. What should I do to solve that problem?

Here are my classes:

**ListExerciseFragment** - fragment which displaying listView

```
public class ListExercisesFragment extends Fragment {
    String TAG="ListExercisesFragment";
    private ExercisesDbAdapter dbHelper;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<Exercise> lExercise=new ArrayList<Exercise>();
    private CustomListAdapter dataAdapter;
    private static  final int REQUEST_CODE=100;
    public ListExercisesFragment(){
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        dbHelper = new ExercisesDbAdapter(getActivity());
        dbHelper.open();

        displayListView();

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position,long id){
                   Exercise exercise=(Exercise) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                   //wysyłam dane do ListDetail
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),ListDetail.class);
                   intent.putExtra("id",exercise.getId());
                   intent.putExtra("name",exercise.getName());
                   intent.putExtra("series",exercise.getSeries());
                   intent.putExtra("reps",exercise.getReps());
                   intent.putExtra("weights",exercise.getWeights());
                   intent.putExtra("notes",exercise.getNotes());
                   intent.putExtra("date",exercise.getDate());
                   startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE);
               }
       });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data){
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_CODE){
            int id=data.getIntExtra("id",-1);
            if(id!=-1){
                Log.d(TAG,"success"+Integer.toString(id));
                deleteExerciseWithID(id);
            }
            else{
                Log.d(TAG,"not working");
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    }


    private void deleteExerciseWithID(int id){
        for(Exercise e:lExercise){
            if( e.getId()==id ){
                dbHelper.deleteRowWithId(id);
                lExercise.remove(e);
                dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void displayListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllExercises();

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int _id = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExercisesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
            int name = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExercisesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME);
            int series = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExercisesDbAdapter.KEY_SERIES);
            int reps = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExercisesDbAdapter.KEY_REPS);
            int weights = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExercisesDbAdapter.KEY_WEIGHTS);
            int notes = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExercisesDbAdapter.KEY_NOTES);
            int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(ExercisesDbAdapter.KEY_DATE);

            Exercise exercise = new Exercise();
            exercise.setId(cursor.getInt(_id));
            exercise.setName(cursor.getString(name));
            exercise.setSeries(cursor.getInt(series));
            exercise.setReps(cursor.getInt(reps));
            exercise.setWeights(cursor.getInt(weights));
            exercise.setNotes(cursor.getString(notes));
            exercise.setDate(cursor.getString(date));


            lExercise.add(exercise);
        }

        Collections.sort(lExercise);


        dataAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(),0, lExercise);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


    }

}
```

**ListDeatil**- class with intent, currently it is displaying exercise's details and by clicking delet button deleting that exercise

```
public class ListDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
String TAG="ListDetails";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_detail);

    final int id=getIntent().getIntExtra("id",-1);
    String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    int series=getIntent().getIntExtra("series",-1);
    int reps=getIntent().getIntExtra("reps",-1);
    int weights=getIntent().getIntExtra("weights",-1);
    String date=getIntent().getStringExtra("date");
    String notes=getIntent().getStringExtra("notes");

    TextView txtName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_name);
    TextView txtSeries=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_series);
    TextView txtReps=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_reps);
    TextView txtWeights=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_weights);
    TextView txtNotes=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_notes);
    TextView txtDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_date);



    txtName.setText(name);
    txtDate.setText(date);
    txtSeries.setText(Integer.toString(series));
    txtReps.setText(Integer.toString(reps));
    txtWeights.setText(Integer.toString(weights));
    txtNotes.setText(notes);

    Log.d(TAG,"Got id: "+Integer.toString(id));

    Button btnDelete=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("id",id);
            setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent intent=new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();

}
}
```

Currently view looks like this:
[ListDetail view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOGTI.png)

I was thinking about create EditTexts, make them GONE at default, when u click on button EDIT, TextViews' visibility from ListDetails class  GONE, EditTexts are VISIBLE, with infos from TextViews, then you will be able to edit it. I have no idea how to write that to be honest. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have created the Demo with two activities one is MainActivity.class which is launcher activity and Second is SecondActivity.class which is second activity.Please go through this both activity you will get the idea:

MainActivity.class

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent iv =new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(iv,1);
    }

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (resultCode){
        case 1:
            Log.d("Edit","Edit");
            break;
        case 2:
            Log.d("Delete","Delete");
            break;
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.class

bt_edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_edit);
        bt_delete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bt_delete);

```
    bt_edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(1);
            finish();

        }
    });


    bt_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setResult(2);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Please check the logs once you click on edit it will go to EditPart of onActivityResult and if you click on delete it will redirect you to Delete Part of OnActivityResult. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but It is not exactly what I wanted to do. I would like on the same activity n btn edit click edit current informations about exercise. After clicking edit button TextView are switching to EditText and then you are able to click OK and update DB record with edited informations.